# Limit a ListIterator to the first N elements (optimized)

Tags: java, collections, iterator, guava

What is a simple and fast way to get an iterator that returns at most N elements from the start of a `List`?

The simplest versions I could come up with are:

#1:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Iterators;

// ...

public static <E> Iterator<E> lengthLimitedIterator(Iterable<E> source, int maxLen) {
    return Iterators.partition(source.iterator(), maxLen).next().iterator();
}
```

#2:

```
public static <E> Iterator<E> lengthLimitedIterator(List<E> source, int maxLen) {
    return source.subList(0, Math.min(source.size(), maxLen)).iterator();
}
```

Unfortunately both versions create a temporary `List` which significantly affects performance as I am calling this method millions of times in a tight loop.

Are there any other library functions I could use for this?

---

Note: I cannot avoid iterating over the list as I am passing it to a method which takes an iterator as its argument and I cannot modify that class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems as if the [feature](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#limit(java.util.Iterator,%20int)) will be added to guava, currently (as of r06) in beta:

```
public static <T> Iterator<T> limit(Iterator<T> iterator, int limitSize)
```

Comment: Besides `Iterators`, note that [`Iterables` also has `limit()` method](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#limit(java.lang.Iterable,%20int)). So if you have a `List`, it's simplest to do `Iterables.limit(aList, 3)`.

Answer (score 15):

You already know it's a list, so you can just call the `List.subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)` method. As per the specification, the subList is backed by the original list, so it's not really creating a full blown `List`, just some kind of proxy object.

Comment: The problem with this is that you have to make sure there are enough available items in the list, or you'll get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. I don't know whether this limitation also exists in the other proposed solutions, but it would be nice to have a builtin option to iterate over _at most_ n elements.

Answer (score 5):

This is a place where a [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) works very well: your decorator keeps a count, which is incremented by `next()`, and used by control `hasNext()`.

Example (intentionally incomplete):

```
public class LengthLimitedIterator<T>
implements Iterator<T>
{
    private Iterator<T> _wrapped;
    private int _length;
    private int _count;

    public LengthLimitedIterator(Iterator<T> wrapped, int length)
    {
        _wrapped = wrapped;
        _length = length;
    }


    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        if (_count < _length)
            return _wrapped.hasNext();
        return false;
    }

    public T next()
    {
        // FIXME - add exception if count >= length
        _count++;
        return _wrapped.next();
    }
```

Comment: With this approach, only one counter is really needed: start at the length and go down to zero.

Answer (score 5):

Why not simply

```
list.subList(0, 42).iterator();
```

I am not sure why you mind about the creation of that temporary list. It doesn't do anything I'd consider expensive. In fact, creating this list is by far cheaper than iterating over it, which I assume you do.

Comment: The receiving method requires an Iterator and unfortunately I cannot change that.  Your code is the same as my second example, except that it does not check for the list being shorter than the maximum length (in which case subList() will throw an exception.)

Answer (score 2):

The `ArrayList.sublist(int,int)` method does not create a copy of the original list.  Instead it returns a SubList instance that wraps the original ArrayList.  The iterator returned by the sublist derived from Array doesn't make a copy either.

So my advice is to try using `ArrayList` as your base list type and the `sublist` method.  If that is not fast enough, implement your own variant of `ArrayList` that implements a `limitedLengthIterator` method.  For example, you should be able to get rid of the code that checks for concurrent modifications.

Comment: But the wrapper is actually slower than the original ArrayList

Comment: @finnw - but it should be faster than copying the list.

Comment: @finnw - Even if you iterate the entire (sub-)list it is likely to be quicker to use a wrapper than to copy elements to a new ArrayList.

Comment: I don't mean "how many elements are iterated", I mean "how many times is the whole sublist iterated over."  In my case it was between 2 and 8 times, and the average sublist length was about 4.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about performance, don't use an Iterator, use an index on an array.  This will give much better performance. Getting the first N elements of an array is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

This version turns out to be faster than any of the other examples:

```
public static <E> Iterator<E> lengthLimitedIterator(List<E> source, int maxLen) {
    maxLen = Math.min(maxLen, source.size());
    ArrayList<E> tempList = new ArrayList<E>(maxLen);
    for (int i = 0; i < maxLen; ++ i) {
       tempList.add(source.get(i));
    }
    return tempList.iterator();
}
```

If the temporary list has to be created anyway, an `ArrayList` is faster than the decorated lists returned by the other library methods.

My guess is that `ArrayList` is getting some special treatment within the VM.

Maybe this would be inefficient for very long lists, but my lists are short (nearly always fewer than 50 elements.)

Comment: Incidentally, I am wary of your "this is faster than that" conclusions, because microbenchmarking in Java is very, VERY error-prone. There are a hundred ways to get a misleading result.

I really think you should try to stick with the clean subList().iterator() solution.

Comment: @Kevin, I've measured it in the real application I'm using it in.  I'm not claiming it's faster in the general case.